# How to save UITextField position, text and background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipangesturerecognizer, userdefaults

I need to save the UITextField text, background color and position.

Saving to defaults to start with but will eventually save to database.

I'd like to be able to drag from the stack to another position ideally but can drag from the center of the view if I can add it there.

```
var TFCount = 1
var TF = UITextField()
var stack = UIStackView()


func addTFToStack()
{
 TF = UITextField()

 TF.text = "\(TFCount)"

 stack.addArrangedSubview(TF)

 TFCount += 1

 let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureHandler(panGesture:)))
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    TF.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.setValue(TF.text, forKey: "TFTextSave")
    defaults.setValue(TF.backgroundColor, forKey: "TFColor")

 let TFSave = defaults.string(forKey: "TFTextSave")
}

func addTFToView()
{
 TF = UITextField()

 TF.text = "\(TFCount)"

 view.addSubview(TF)

 TFCount += 1

 let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureHandler(panGesture:)))
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    TF.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.setValue(TF.text, forKey: "TFTextSave")
    defaults.setValue(TF.backgroundColor, forKey: "TFColor")

 let TFSave = defaults.string(forKey: "TFTextSave")
}


@objc func panGestureHandler(panGesture recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    if recognizer.state == .began
    {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: view)
        TF.center = location
    }
    else
    {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: view)
        TF.center = location
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
  addTFToStack()
}
```

Comment: If you have a question, not a request, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can use the `translation` method of the pan gesture recognizer to achieve what you want to do:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 0
    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
    
    @objc func panned(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let touchedView = gestureRecognizer.view else { return }
        for case let subview as UITextField in self.view.subviews {
            if touchedView.contains(subview) {
                let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: touchedView.superview)
                switch gestureRecognizer.state {
                    case .began,.changed:
                        var center = subview.center
                        center.x += translation.x
                        center.y += translation.y
                        subview.center = center
                        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: touchedView.superview)
                    default:
                        break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first, let touchedView = touch.view else { return }
        var location = touch.location(in: touchedView)
        location.x -= size.width / 2
        location.y -= size.height / 2
        count += 1
        
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: location, size: size))
        textField.backgroundColor = .orange
        textField.text = "\(count)"
        
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panned))
        textField.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
    }

}
```

You also have to make sure to use the `setTranslation` at the end to reset the beginning location to zero.